# How to manage the states of an outgoing call in Android?

Tags: android, phone-call

I'm developing an android application for a university exam.
I use a Samsung Galaxy S3 with original ROM, Android Jelly Bean 4.3.

I have a problem with detecting the "states" of an outgoing call.
I need to know when the phone call "start" from my application and "stop" (rejected or not) because i have to pause and restart the playing song of a music service.

I have already done it with the incoming calls and it works perfectly in this way:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

    if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
        if (Start.getMusicService().isPlaying()) {
            pauseService();

            isMusicPlaying = true;
        }
    }
    else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
        if (isMusicPlaying){
            startService();

            isMusicPlaying = false;
        }
    }
}
```

For the outgoing calls i register the receiver in the manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".Music.OutgoingCallReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and add the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
```

I tried this solution for the receiver

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephonyManager.listen(new PhoneStateListener() {
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String number) {

            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                if (Start.getMusicService().isPlaying()) {
                    pauseService();

                    isMusicPlaying = true;
                }
            }
            else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                if (isMusicPlaying){
                    startService();

                    isMusicPlaying = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}
```

I have already read other questions buy i didn't find the answer.
I hope you can help me.

Andrea

Comment: onReceive is not getting called at all? How did you set up the BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: @Rarw i edit my question with the method onReceive.
It is called correctly every time but in the method i'm not able to do what i need

Comment: If you just want to modulate the volume of your app when there is a call, you could also use the audio focus : https://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html

Comment: For incoming calls does this work if the app is closed and you are at the home screen? I ask because if this receiver was in a activity, it would not be active once the app was closed to make an outgoing call.

Comment: @ValentinRocher I'd like to pause the song and at the end of the call restart from the same point.

Comment: @Rarw when i close my application i stop the service, so i can't try.

Comment: So you've only tried it with the app open. That's your problem. None of this will have any effect if the service is already stopped or the application is destroyed so that there is no broadcast receiver to handle the message. You should keep your service alive and try to receive the messages there.

Comment: @andrea92 : if you read the link I gave you, this is a way to do this kind of things properly

Answer (score 0):

make procedure to read logcat of radio,
command:

```
logcat -d -b radio RILJ:D RILC:D *:S
```

mine on android 2.3, when make outgoing call got output:

```
06-11 20:38:43.051 D/RILJ    (  429): [4678]< GET_CURRENT_CALLS  [id=1,ALERTING,toa=145,norm,mo,0,voc,noevp,,cli=1,,1]
```

and when answered got output:

```
06-11 20:38:50.300 D/RILJ    (  429): [4683]< GET_CURRENT_CALLS  [id=1,ACTIVE,toa=145,norm,mo,0,voc,noevp,,cli=1,,1]
```

so, to detect wether outgoingcall is answered,
me make procedure to capture those logs and check if it

```
contain time > time-when-make-outgoing-call, and
contains string "GET_CURRENT_CALLS" and "ACTIVE".
```

and... IT WORKS, for me on sonyericsson-android 2.3.

i don't know if it works on other device and android version, you tell me.

Comment: How to write java code for above concept which can be used in android application itself?